# How to know exactly why SQL SERVER 2014 Express installation failed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I downloaded `ExpressAndTools 64BIT\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299). When I tried to install it I get the following error:

[image]

But it does not say exactly what I have missing.

My environment is configured as follows:

- Windows 7 Ulitimate 64 bits
- 4 GB of RAM and enough HDD space
- Intel i3 processor (enough for SQL SERVER 2014)
- .Net 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 installed on my computer

Still it says something is wrong without even telling me what.

How to solve that issue?

Comment: It seems you haven't meet the Config requirements. Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: The error is saying you don't have the proper OS Version or Service Pack level. You say you're running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit but does it have SP1?

Comment: @SeanGallardy true I don t have SP1... Did not think it was required

Comment: @  Oh yeah Sean I just checked.. SP1 is required... My mistake

Comment: @SeanGallardy I updated my Windows with SP1 and all .Net versions but I still get the sme error

Comment: any luck @JasonKrs? Were you able to install it finally?

Comment: @ManojPandey Wow I that a LONG time a ago. I don't even remember.... But, I voted up the comment of  `Sean Gallardy` above. I think it means I did not have the proper SP installed. Try it an let us know in an answer if successful

Answer (score 1):

If you can open the SQL Server Installation Center with this installer it will give you a lot of useful info.

In the Planning section you can find the Hardware & Software requirements. Or: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: The problem is that I can't even open the the installer. The only thing I get when I double click `setup` is the popup I posted.  I updated my OS to SP1 plus all .Net versions but I still get the same popup